# Moved VM doesnt work correctly on my Ubuntu machine

Tags: windows-7, vmware-player

I have a Windows 7 VM that I have moved onto my Ubuntu 64bit host machine that is running VMware player 3.1.0. I think the VM was created on a Windows host.

The problem I have is that when I login to this VM the screen goes blank and stays that way. The login screen is fine, but the desktop never correctly appears and sort of shows some strange pixelation that is all distorted. Seems like a virtual video card issue?

If I boot into safe mode the desktop appears fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do other VM's work fine in the player?  Have you tried reverting to an earlier time in the VM?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed (sort of) my problem by disabling the "Accelerate 3D graphics" check box in the display settings of the VM